# Rolling dataset having different row numbers

Tags: r, dataset

My sample data is as follows.
There are event, datetime and ten_minute. 
The format of datetime is "POSIXlt" "POSIXt". Ten minute is just a substring of the first digit of minute in datetime variable.

[image]

I’d like to generate multiple rolling dataset using R. For example, Data_1 have rows with ten_minute value of 0, 1, 2. Data_2 have rows with ten_minute value of 1, 2, 3. (And finally, Data_n would have value of 3, 4, 5.) I also want to change the width of window. In this example the width of window is 3. I want to change the width to 5, 10 and etc.

I've tried R coding myself over a week. But I can't figure it out how to do this.

Comment: Can you post the data in a format we can load easily into R and not do extra work? Also, can you confirm if you are looking to retrieve multiple data frames, and not just a single data frame.

Comment: `l <- lapply(list(0:2, 1:3, 0:4), function(x) data[data$Ten_minute %in% x, ])`

Comment: I want multiple data frames.

Comment: Event  Datetime Ten_minute 
A 2015-12-10 06:02:11 0
A 2015-12-10 06:04:42 0
A 2015-12-10 06:07:52 0
B 2015-12-10 06:10:13 1
A 2015-12-10 06:11:02 1
C 2015-12-10 06:14:31 1
C 2015-12-10 06:18:43 1
A 2015-12-10 06:20:22 2 
B 2015-12-10 06:28:35 2
D 2015-12-10 06:31:54 3
A 2015-12-10 06:37:16 3
A 2015-12-10 06:39:29 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a function to generate the windows you need:

```
generate.windows <- function(vec.start, vec.numberofsets, vec.wdith) {
    vec.sets <- vec.start:vec.numberofsets
    lapply(vec.sets, function(n) {
           seq(from = n, length.out = vec.wdith)})}
```

Next, extract the data.frames that correspond to each window:

```
# Assume your original data set is called df.data
list.windows <- generate.windows(1, 10, 3)
list.data.frames <- lapply(list.windows, function(n) {df.data[df.data[,"Ten_minute"] %in% n,]}
```